# Read .txt file from maven project in java using executable file in linux shell

Tags: java, linux, maven

I want to read a `.txt` file from a java project on click of an executable file in linux based command prompt in a manner as shown below

> ./xyz inputs.txt

where xyz is the executable file and inputs is the input file. The executable file will launch the main class which is to read the `inputs.txt` file and proceed.
Please Note: It is compulsory to use the command as shown above

Answer (score 0):

So what is your problem? You trying to read it from the terminal or from some IDE?

Comment: I accomplished this task as I was able to retrieve the filename from this command using String args[] parameter in main function and hence read it from there.